# Referring to compiler-generated variables from my CoffeeScript code

Tags: coffeescript

In CoffeeScript, I could loop over an array like this:

```
for d,i in [1,2,3,4,5]
  console.log "Thing #{i+1}/#{_len} is #{d}"
```

...but should I? I've taken advantage of the compiler-generated `_len` variable to avoid making my own array length calculation.

I get the feeling that referring to `_len` is not the best practice, but I don't want to make my own array length check/calculation because (1) it's duplicated effort and (2) it's an extra line of code.

What is the lesser of these two evils? Should I use `_len` or add a LoC by making my own?

Comment: I would choose LOC, it will increase clarity

Comment: Executive summary: don't do it, don't even think about it. If necessary, you can `for ... in a = [...]` if you prefer "cleverness" over clarity.